# no php error file even though error_log is defined in php.ini

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, error-logging, error-log

i am running php 5.5.20 in my amazon ec2 linux box. I have done the following in the terminal

```
[root]# cat /etc/php.ini | grep error_log

; server-specific log, STDERR, or a location specified by the error_log
; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
;error_log = php_errors.log
;error_log = syslog
error_log = /var/log/httpd/php_errors.log
```

Note that the `error_log` directive is not commented out. However, i am facing errors (namely 404 errors, PDO errors etc) in my website but the php_errors.log file is not even being created.

I also tried `chmod 777 /var/log/httpd/` as well... but even that didn't help

I also checked that `log_errors` directive is set to `On` in `php.ini` settings

Comment: Did you change the `error_directive` yourself? If so, did you also reboot your server instance? Not sure, but I think [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html) is relevant.

Comment: i have done `service httpd restart`... i did restart my ec2 instance... what is the `error_directive` you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `error_log` directive. Mixed up my words.

Comment: yes i changed the `error_log` directive myself... actually i didn't change it... i added the uncommented `error_log` directive... the commented `error_log` directives were present by default

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the correct file.

I've seen EC2 users have php.ini locations like `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

You could also try `locate php.ini` in your shell.

Comment: i also did `<? phpinfo() ?>` in my php file. The error_log path that is being shown there is indeed the path i have defined in `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: Maybe just try.. `error_log php_errors.log` - That should put the file in the same directory as your script. This should tell us whether or not it's a ownership/permissions issue.